# IIS can't find PHP files

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012, fastcgi

I am running Windows Server 2012 with IIS. I have enabled CGI and installed PHP with IIS FastCGI and Multi-Byte strings. It is also the Non-Thread safe version. Though, I have made a PHP file to test PHP but IIS just gives me an 404.3 error. I have reinstalled IIS and PHP and it still doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404.3 means that you have not configured a handler for .php files. Take a look at [the PHP documentation for how to configure this](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) it's approximately halfway down the page.